# Most Efficient Way to Compare 2 Primitives in Java?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, logic, micro-optimization

Which code is better or optimized or efficient?

```
double a;
double b;

if (a == b)
  return true;
```

or

```
if (a - b == 0)
   return true;
```

Comment: in what language ? The first should be fastest because it's one operation, unless you work on a very specific system but I doubt that the others would be faster somewhere.

Comment: Note that they do very different things. Consider `a=4, b=2`... then `a%b==0`, but `a != b`.

Comment: Your title is horrible, it has nothing to do with your question, anyone searching for it will never find it.  Rename it to something regarding comparison or equallity.

Comment: `a % b` isn't necessarily `a == b` or `a - b`

Comment: on another note worrying about the performance of 1 line is overkill unless you know this line/method is executed most of your computation time.

Comment: Always think twice before comparing floats or doubles using `==`. Rounding may cause values that should have been the same not to be equal. For most purposes, test whether the difference is within some suitably narrow margin.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks for your reply.. then whats should be done if == is not suitable for rounding purpose. margin check needs more code and memory i think.

Comment: A bit more code, yes, if any more memory, it’s neglectable. One option is `if (Math.abs(a - b)) < THRESHOLD)` … Last time I used `1e-11`, but the correct choice of threshold will depend on the context.

Comment: should you really use a threshold like that ? Isn't a multiple of the ulp better ?

Comment: *Floating point math is hard.  You just won’t believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly hard it is. I mean, you may think it’s difficult to calculate when trains from Chicago and Los Angeles will collide, but that’s just peanuts to floating-point math.*  See [Bruce Dawson's excellent article](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) about FP comparisons.  @HopefullyHelpful and Ole, you folks should have a look; Bruce discusses the merits of absolute thresholds vs. epsilon vs. relative ULP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a % b == 0` does not imply that `a` equals `b`. So the compiler cannot optimise this out.

As for the other two, you ought to use `a == b` as it's clearer, and leave the optimisations to the compiler.

Comment: More importantly, any decent compiler can and *will* optimize `a == b` to the same code as `a - b == 0`, if those expressions are equivalent.  (e.g. they're not for floating point, where `a-b` can raise an FP inexact result exception, but `a==b` can't, at least in ISO C.)